# How to remove only minutes from UIDatePickerMode.DateAndTime

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, datepicker

Is there way to remove only minutes from `UIDatePickerMode`? I tried to search many posts and i still haven't find.
I see Date, Time , Date and Time, Count Down Timer from `DatePicker` Menu

The following image is got by choosing Date and Time.

[image: <code>UIDatePickerMode.DateAndTime</code>]

But I need to do is like following image.

[image: Image from designer]

Any ideas, tips? Thank you!

Comment: that is not possible with UIDatePicker. You probably have to create your own. probably using UIPicker.

Comment: for your concept go for UIpicker View

Comment: Yeah you guys are right. I need to use 'UIPickerView' instead of 'UIDatePicker'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Christian mentioned, you can't edit the `UIDatePicker`. What you can do is use a `UIPickerView`. Implement the `dataSource` to return `3 components`, 1 for each column. Then have an array for the possible options for `month`, `day` and `hour time`.

dataSource:

```
let monthsArray = ["august"..]
var daysArray = [1..31] //include logic for actual days of the month
let hoursArray = ["1pm"..]

func numberOfComponentsInPickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
   return 3
}

func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
   switch component {
   case 1: return monthsArray.count
   case 2: return daysArray.count
   case 3: return hoursArray.count
   }
}
```

you also need to implement the delegate for knowing what the user has selected

```
func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int)
```

Comment: Yeah you guys are right. I need to use `UIPickerView` instead of `UIDatePicker`